# Spark DataGrid multiline header renderer

Tags: flex4, flex-spark, flex-datagrid

I have a data grid and one of its columns has a long header text, so I want to span it across multiple lines. I tried several things but to no avail. Here's my current code:

```
<s:GridColumn rendererIsEditable="true" sortable="false">
                <s:headerRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <s:GridItemRenderer>
                            <s:layout><s:HorizontalLayout horizontalAlign="center"/></s:layout>
                            <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="Allow Spillover" verticalAlign="middle" maxDisplayedLines="2"
                                toolTip="Allow campaign spillover if the impression goal was not reached by the defined end date. Enabled only if a Periodic or Total Impressions were defined in the ‘General Capping’ section. Maximum Spillover is until next configured flight date."/>
                        </s:GridItemRenderer>
                    </fx:Component>
                </s:headerRenderer>
```

As can be seen, I set maxDisplayedLines to 2, but the text still doesn't break, but spills outside of the column. What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

follow this link for answer

[How to center a header renderer in a Spark data grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591296/how-to-center-a-header-renderer-in-a-spark-data-grid/16608224#16608224)

just change the `maxDisplayedLines` in `Label` of Header Renderer