# How to center a header renderer in a Spark data grid?

Tags: flex4, flex-spark, flex-datagrid

Currently I have this code:

```
<s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer maxDisplayedLines="2" textAlign="center"/>
```

But it's not working, even though I have `textAlign="center"`!
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Make your own `<s:DefaultGridHeaderRenderer />` and add/edit below line to get center aligned header.

```
<s:Label id="labelDisplay" 
            verticalCenter="1" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
            textAlign="center"
            fontWeight="bold"
            verticalAlign="middle"
            maxDisplayedLines="1"
            showTruncationTip="true" />
```